# Can I use NSLayoutConstraints to keep a UIView's subviews equally spaced regardless of later adding or removing from the subviews array?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nslayoutconstraint

I'd like to have a UIView where, every time I add or remove subviews from its `subviews` array, whichever subviews happent to be in the array are still equally spaced.

For example, if I have subviews a and b spaced 10 points appart, like so:

**[a]-10-[b]**

and then add a view c, the views in `subviews` should now be automatically laid out like this:

**[a]-10-[b]-10-[c]**

If, however I now remove view b, the gap in between a and c should update to be once again 10 points:

**[a]-10-[c]**

I know I can use NSLayoutConstraint to create this type of constraint between two known views, and I guess I could also set up a KVO where each time the array changes I could cycle through all subviews and re-apply the constraint but I'm wondering if there is an automatic way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your code that calculates the constraints based on the current subviews is in updateConstraints:

```
- (void)updateConstraints {
    [super updateConstraints];
    // Put your code here
}
```

Then you just need to call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` whenever you add/remove a subview.

Comment: `UIView` has hooks you can use to notice this automatically: `didAddSubview:` & `willRemoveSubview:`